# How do I calculate the size of a Cassandra Partition?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, datamodel

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS video (key int, value int, PRIMARY KEY (key, value));
```

Here Partition Key is `key` and Clustering Key is `value`. No regular columns.
Assume, there are 1000000 rows in this partition.

What is the size of the partition?

Comment: So…. How large are the integer values that are being stored?

Comment: Please consider all the values to be worst case. MAX number for integer. @Aaron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To calculate the partition size, you need the following data points:

- size of the partition key columns
- size of static columns
- size of cells in the partition (clustering + regular columns)
- size of metadata overhead per row

In your case:

- the size the partition key (a single `int` column) is `4 bytes`
- the size of static columns (there are none) is `0 bytes`
- the size of the cells (clustering  `int` + `0` regular columns) is `4 + 0 bytes`
- the size of the metadata overhead is `8 bytes` on average

So for 1M rows:

```
partition size = 4B + 0B + (4B x 1,000,000 cells) + (8B x 1,000,000,000 rows)
               = 12,000,004 bytes
               = 11.44 MB
```

Cheers!

Comment: Awesome @ErickRamirez. Could you also please post a link for various data types and their size? For e.g. where did you find `int` column occupying `4 bytes`?

Comment: They are Java objects and this question was easy because a Java integer has a fixed size. It gets hard for other data types like CQL `text` because they're not fixed so you can only guess. Cheers!

Comment: @ErickRamirez is the meta data overhead for the row or cell ?

Comment: For the row. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

1. Insert the desired number of records into your Cassandra table.
2. Wait for the [flush](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/4.1/cassandra/configuration/cass_yaml_file.html#commitlog_sync_period) to happen persisting records to the disk or invoke `nodetool flush` manually on your cluster node(s).
3. Navigate to the data directory. By default, [`data_file_directories`](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/4.1/cassandra/configuration/cass_yaml_file.html#data_file_directories) will be persisting data to `/var/lib/cassandra/data`. Switch to <your_table_name-timeuuid> formatted directory
4. List the [<sstable_version-Data.db> file](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/4.1/cassandra/architecture/storage_engine.html#sstable-versions) to view its size. Note that this is just on a single node size. If you have more than one node in your cluster, you'd have to repeat the steps to calculate size on each node.
5. Alternatively, you could also run [`nodetool tablestats` command](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/4.1/cassandra/tools/nodetool/tablestats.html#tablestats) on each node to understand statistics about a particular table.